# Auto Increment Id on multiple spring boot entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 class in my spring boot application and in all of these 3 classes i am using a vaiable sNo (serial No) which is primary key of that table

After running spring boot application a domain hibernate_sequence is automatically created in database
which contains

```
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|     1    |
|     1    |
|     1    |
+----------+
```

Now i am using one end point for saving some users in my db.
For example i save 3892 rows(records) in my users table after that my hibernate_sequence contains.

```
+----------+
| next_val |
+----------+
|     3893 |
|     3893 |
|     3893 |
+----------+
```

Now suppose i want to save one row in application table then serial number is now starting from 3894.

**How i manage or control this auto increment serial number in my multiple spring boot entity?**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    Long sNo
    // Rest of the fields
}

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "applications")
    class Application {
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @GeneratedValue
        Long sNo
        // Rest of the fields
    }
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_activity")
    class UserActivity {
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @GeneratedValue
        Long sNo
        // Rest of the fields
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Changes Need to be done in application.yml file

```
properties:
      hibernate:
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
```